# JSOM Update web part properties doesn't always work

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject, content-query-web-part

Here is a code snippet (there is applicable code to get to this point, of course):

```
var properties = oWebPart.get_properties();

properties.set_item("FilterDisplayValue1", "M");
properties.set_item("TitleUrl", "http://amisherakefight.org");

oWebPartDefinition.saveWebPartChanges();
clientContext.load(oWebPartDefinition);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

It is to change a Content Query web part's filter programmatically.  The code before this leverages *.getLimitedWebPartManager()* related calls.

What is interesting is that the filter doesn't get changed but the title URL property does.

Any ideas on what is going awry?  Thanks in advance...